# Can't access https web service from web server - Schannel fatal alert: 40

Tags: windows-server-2008, ssl, asp.net, pci-dss, web-services

About a month ago our code to access a web service started failing, and gives an error relating to SSL connection:

```
System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel. at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context) at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream() at
```

The following error is logged in Event Viewer.

Event ID: 36887 - "The following fatal alert was received: 40."

It is Windows Server 2008 64-bit. It is set up for PCI compliance so there has been changes to do with SSL when the server was setup to make it comply, but no recent changes before this stopped working.

On the server, if I try and access using Internet Explorer the HTTPS URL of the web service it says it can't display the page, and the same event is logged. This also happens on some other HTTPS websites I tried.

If I access using Google Chrome on the same server, it works fine.

In my C# ASP.NET code I have tried ignoring SSL errors, but this didn't help:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
```

I also read about a November 2014 update that might have caused the issue, but the later update to fix it seems to have already been installed.

Any ideas on what else I can try?

Comment: Check your ssl cypher order "client" i don't see other problems. A lot of people disabled SSL2 and SSL3 in november. And for the patch Microsoft had patch the patch for the cipher problem in november :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution... I used an application called [IIS Crypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/), which changes the registry settings for SSL protocols, ciphers, hashes, key exchangers and the order of SSL ciphers, to set these all to the optimal configuration for PCI compliance. After a server restart not only could Internet Explorer access the HTTPS page, but the code that accesses the web service started working again.